# How to put records from two different tables into one column through SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, for context, this is how I'm trying to arrange the information: if the event is a movie, list the genre. If the event is a play - list the name of the author. The fourth column will be called called 'Genre/Author'.

Movie is a table, and Play is a table.

I don't now how to list the respective information without the query results being separate or not returning anything.

This is what I have tried:

```
    SELECT E.EventName, 
    V.VenueID, 
    E.Description, 
    (M.Genre AND P.Author) as 'Genre/Author' 
    FROM ( Event as E LEFT OUTER JOIN Venue as V
        ON E.VenueID = V.VenueID )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Movie as M ON E.EventCode = M.EventCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Play as P ON E.EventCode = P.EventCode;
```

When that query returned records, the 'Genre/Author' column said "0" down the line.

```
    SELECT E.EventName, 
    V.VenueID, 
    E.Description, 
    M.Genre as Genre,
    P.Author as Author
    FROM ( Event as E LEFT OUTER JOIN Venue as V
        ON E.VenueID = V.VenueID )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Movie as M ON E.EventCode = M.EventCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Play as P ON E.EventCode = P.EventCode;
```

The query above returned the correct information, but I want to combine Genre and Author into one column. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` to select the required column based on the eventname. Change the conditions as per the data in the table. Also, this column would be `null` for all other eventnames.

```
SELECT E.EventName, 
V.VenueID, 
E.Description, 
case when e.eventname = 'Movie' then M.Genre 
     when e.eventname 'Play' then P.Author 
end as Genre/Author
FROM Event as E 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Venue as V ON E.VenueID = V.VenueID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Movie as M ON E.EventCode = M.EventCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Play as P ON E.EventCode = P.EventCode
```

Comment: So, I haven't used case before so I'm not very familiar with it. 

When I tried to play around with the case syntax, the query returned NULL for the entire column. 

But I think this is on the right track, Movie and Play are separate tables that are not a part of the Event table. So I need to find a way to show an Event is a Movie or a Play.